# How can I add text automatically from text in another column in ms-project using VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-project

i have column Mold number(Text5) and i want to add automatically text for Product Name(Text2)
*For example* if Mold number(Text5) = 111 , Product Name(Text2) "Trapez" will be created automatically
And this is my code

```
Sub AddProductName()
Dim Name As String
Dim tsk As Task
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Select Case True
        Case (tsk.Text5 Like "*111*"): Name = "Trapez"
        Case Else: Name = vbNullString
        End Select

    If Len(Name) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        tsk.Text2 = Name
        End If
    End If

Next tsk

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Small list of values

A customized field works well for a small list of values. Customize the Text2 field with this formula:  `Switch([Text5] Like "*1111*","AA",[Text5] Like "*1234*","AB",[Text5] Like "*1233*","BB",[Text5] Like "*1232*","BA",True,"")`

[image: how to add formula to customize a field]

### Large list of values

For a large list of possible values in the Text5 field, use a macro like this. The downside to using a macro is that changes to the Text5 field will not be reflected in the Text2 field until the macro is run. (Note: unlike Excel which has a Change event at the cell level, Project does not have a task-level change event.)

```
Sub AddProductName()

Dim ProductName As String
Dim tsk As Task

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not tsk Is Nothing Then

        Select Case True
            Case (tsk.Text5 Like "*1111*"): ProductName = "AA"
            Case (tsk.Text5 Like "*1234*"): ProductName = "AB"
            Case (tsk.Text5 Like "*1233*"): ProductName = "BB"
            Case (tsk.Text5 Like "*1232*"): ProductName = "BA"
            Case Else: ProductName = vbNullString
        End Select

        tsk.Text2 = ProductName
    End If
Next tsk

End Sub
```